# Django - i have add onclick function into html and whenever i click into different button then it will render the same data. how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

```
    <div class="home-food-row">
    {% if allmenu %} {% for menu in allmenu %}
    <div class="home-food-menu-col">
    <div class="filterDiv breakfast">
    <div class="img-price-tag">
    <div class="price-tag" id="price">{{menu.price}} only</div>
    <img class="home-page-food-img" src="{{menu.food_img.url}}" alt="Food" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <h1 id="foodName_1">{{menu.food_name}}</h1>
    <p>{{menu.food_description}}</p>
    <button id="order" onclick="myFunction()">Place Order</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} {% else %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>No Food</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

/////////////////////////// JS Code ////////////////////////////

```
    function myFunction() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price");
    var food = document.getElementById("foodName_1");
    console.log(food);
    console.log(price);
   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsyvl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhtqM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason: all your menus have the same id.  You can use the id of the menu to give each one a unique id, by appending `{{ menu.id }}` to the id attribute in your html.

```html
    <div class="home-food-row">
    <strike> {% if allmenu %} {% for menu in allmenu %} <strike>
    <div class="home-food-menu-col">
    <div class="filterDiv breakfast">
    <div class="img-price-tag">
    <div class="price-tag" id="price{{ menu.id }}">{{menu.price}} only</div>
    <img class="home-page-food-img" src="{{menu.food_img.url}}" alt="Food" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <h1 id="foodName_1{{ menu.id }}">{{menu.food_name}}</h1>
    <p>{{menu.food_description}}</p>
    <button id="order" onclick="myFunction('{{ menu.id }}')">Place Order</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <strike>{% endfor %} {% else %}<strike>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>No Food</p>
    </div>
    <strike>  {% endif %}<strike>
    </div>
```

Then you can target these individually in your javascript like this:

```js
    function myFunction(id) {
    var price = document.getElementById("price" + id);
    var food = document.getElementById("foodName_1" + id);
    console.log(food);
    console.log(price);
   }
```

Comment: it will return the null value, I did exactly the same

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why you're getting a null value.  This should work.  Where are you getting the null value?  In `console.log(food)`?

Comment: we can not pass {{menu.id}} into on click function right ? while passing values from on click function then I got an error and values didn't pass, is there is any other way so that I can pass my values to js

Comment: I got null values on both in console.log(food) and   console.log(price);

Comment: Typo on my part, I edited the answer.  You can pass the variable, but I forgot to wrap it in single quotes: `<button id="order" onclick="myFunction('{{ menu.id }}')">`

Comment: I got null values on both in console.log(food) and console.log(price); –

Comment: function myFunction(id) {
  var price = document.getElementById("price" + id);
  var food = document.getElementById("foodName_1" + id);
  console.log(food);
  console.log(price);
}
this is my code on js

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why.  This should work.  Did you change `onclick="myFunction({{ menu.id }})">` to `onclick="myFunction('{{ menu.id }}')">`?  Does `console.log(id)` show anything?  Does adding `{{ menu.id }}` show anything in your template?  Maybe try `{{ menu.pk }}` instead.

Comment: yes, it's showing its id and I don't know why the value is sowing null

Comment: Hi @ShivaGiri.  If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: how to mark this question as done. i don't have any idea why I leave it as is it

Comment: Hi @ShivaGiri, just click the check-mark ( ✓ ) below the ⯆0⯅ and it will turn green.  If you wish you can also click the ⯅ to up-vote the answer.  Check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. And no worries if it doesn't work, it was a pleasure to be of help.

Comment: thanks for telling me, now you can check

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ideal would be to make a view which accepts a parameter with which you can identify your object, an example would be:

```
def vote_site_view(request, slug_name):
    with transaction.atomic():
        site = Site.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).filter(
            slug_name=slug_name, deleted=False
        )
        site.update(votes=F("votes") + 1)
    return JsonResponse({"message": "ok"}, status=200)
```

In HTML:

```
<button class="vote-btn like" onclick="voteSite('{{ site.slug_name }}')">
  <i class="icon ico-like"></i>
</button>
```

Finally in your Js file:

```
function voteSite(slug_name) {
  let url = `${window.location.origin}/vote/${slug_name}/`;
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      alert(response.data.message);
    });
}
```